# Python, ExcelWriter - Add formatting into existing Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have Excel file with data written on it. I am trying to add some formatting to columns, but it doesn't work:

```
def format_file(dataset, path):
    try:
        for r in data_set:
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
            book = writer.book
            # sheet = book.get_worksheet_by_name(r["name"]) - didn't work
            sheet = writer.sheets[r["name"]] # doesn't work neither
            try:
                for i, value in enumerate(r['data'].columns.values):
                    # here I set formatting attributes, so will cut this part as it works
                    
                    format = book.add_format({'align' : align, 'num_format' : num_format, 'color' : color})

                    sheet.set_solumn(i, i, width, format_text)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            writer.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return path
```

I receive "NoneType object has no attribute set_column" exceptions.

My main idea is to open Excel file (dataset in arguments is already written on it) and add formatting to columns. Could you, please, help me, how to improve my code?

Comment: in what line do you get the NoneType errors? You have a typo in the line sheet.set_solumn(... You mean sheet.set_column(

Comment: Yes, thank you, changed by accident, but still receiving this error on line sheet.set_column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First from the error message `NoneType object has no attribute set_column` we can guess that there is no sheet with name `r["name"]`.

And check the docstring of `pd.ExcelWriter`, the default file-open mode of `pd.ExcelWriter` is `w` which means it will wipe out all existing contents in the file after opening:

```
Help on class ExcelWriter in module pandas.io.excel._base:

class ExcelWriter(builtins.object)
 |  ExcelWriter(path: 'FilePath | WriteExcelBuffer | ExcelWriter', engine: 'str | None' = None, date_format: 'str | None' = None, datetime_format: 'str | None' = None, mode: 'str' = 'w', storage_options: 'StorageOptions' = None, if_sheet_exists: "Literal['error', 'new', 'replace', 'overlay'] | None" = None, engine_kwargs: 'dict | None' = None, **kwargs) -> 'ExcelWriter'
 |  
 |  Class for writing DataFrame objects into excel sheets.
 |  
 |  Default is to use:
 |  
 |  * `xlwt <https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/>`__ for xls files
 |  * `xlsxwriter <https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/>`__ for xlsx files if xlsxwriter
 |    is installed otherwise `openpyxl <https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/>`__
 |  * `odswriter <https://pypi.org/project/odswriter/>`__ for ods files
 |  
 |  See ``DataFrame.to_excel`` for typical usage.
 |  
  ...

 |  mode : {'w', 'a'}, default 'w'
 |      File mode to use (write or append). Append does not work with fsspec URLs.
  ...
```

Therefore no matter what sheets you had in the file, they will be cleared.

Also, engine of 'xlsxwriter' doesn't support file-open mode of 'a'.

Given above the solution of your issue could be:

1. if your data writing is also in the same function and you want to stick with engine `xlsxwriter`, what you need to do is move the creation of `writer` out of the loop (otherwise the the file opening operation of current dataset will wipe out previous written data):

```py
def format_file(dataset, path):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    try:
        for r in data_set:
            r["data"].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=r["name"]) # assuming your data stored in r["data"] in the format of pd.DataFrame
            book = writer.book
            # sheet = book.get_worksheet_by_name(r["name"]) - didn't work
            sheet = writer.sheets[r["name"]] # doesn't work neither
            try:
                for i, value in enumerate(r['data'].columns.values):
                    # here I set formatting attributes, so will cut this part as it works
                    
                    format = book.add_format({'align' : align, 'num_format' : num_format, 'color' : color})

                    sheet.set_solumn(i, i, width, format_text)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        writer.close()
    return path
```

(Note the code is just for illustration purpose, I didn't run it and possibly there is bug)

2. If you are editing an existing excel file, you will have to switch to [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl)
   engine as `xlsxwriter` engine doesn't support append mode.